# Setting the accessibility text on a QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, pyqt, accessibility, pyqt5, screen-readers

My application contains several instances of `QTreeWidget` and the person who is helping me with accessibility testing has told me that there's a problem with the trees and the screen reader they're using (JAWS).

The screen reader provides no indication that a collapsed tree node has children and can be expanded.

In other situations where I've needed to provide additional information to the reader, I've used the `setAccessibleName` method provided by `QWidget`, but that's not available for `QTreeWidgetItem`.

Is there a way to specify the accessibility text for a `QTreeWidgetItem`, or am I going to have to re-implement my trees in some other way?

Comment: Try passing him a delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further experimentation led me to believe that this may be avoidable by using the `setItemWidget` method provided by `QTreeWidget` and providing a `QLabel`, since that does inherit from `QWidget` and therefore does have methods like `setAccessibleName` and `setAccessibleDescription`.

Comment: How did you resolve? Is there any way without adding QLabel?

Comment: I didn't anything else after using setItemWidget and QLabel, but I don't remember if it was because I left the project or because I never heard anything back from the accessibility tester about it.